# Rails 5 how to create nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

**fuel_consumption.rb**

```
class FuelConsumption < ApplicationRecord
  after_initialize :set_defaults, unless: :persisted?

  def set_defaults
    self.date ||= Date.today
  end

  belongs_to :boiler
  validates :fuel, numericality: {message: 'Поле может быть только числовое'}
  validates :fuel, presence: 'Поле топлива не может быть пустым'
  validates_uniqueness_of :date, scope: :boiler_id, message: 'Эта дата уже заполнена'
  validates :date, presence: 'Дата не может быть пустой'
end
```

**new.html.slim**

```
h4 Расход топлива
  = form_for(@branch, url: {action: 'create'}, method: 'post') do |f|
    = f.fields_for :boilers do |ff|
      = ff.fields_for :fuel_consumption do |fff|
        .form-group
          = fff.label :fuel, 'Дата'
          = fff.text_field :date, class: 'form-control', disabled: 'disabled', value: I18n.l(Date.today, format: :long)
        .form-group
          = fff.label :fuel, 'Количество топлива'
          = fff.text_field :fuel, class: 'form-control'
    .form-group
      = f.submit 'Сохранить', class: "btn btn-lg btn-success"
```

**fuel_consumption_controller.rb**

```
  def new
    @branch = current_user.branches.first
    # @fuel_consumption = FuelConsumption.new
  end
  def create
    @branch = current_user.branch.update_attributes(branch_params)

    if @branch
      render :success
    else
      flash.alert = 'Oops'
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end


  def branch_params
    params.require(:branch).permit!
  end
```

I have assigned to user 1 branch, which have few (4 or 5) boilers, and i want to create fuel consumption on each boiler from one page, how to achieve that. 
This code updates attributes, but doesn't create fuel_consumption.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you forgot to allow the nested attributes to be set in your model(s), for example in `models/branch`:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :boilers
```

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the above answer you should double check if you permit the params in your controller. There are some very nice tutorials on setting up nested attributes.

For instance: 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Hope it helps.